# How many Unicode encodings are there, and are all of them still in use?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I know of the following Unicode encodings:

- UTF-7
- UTF-8
- UTF-16
- UTF-32
- UCS-2

Are there more Unicode encodings? And are all of the Unicode encodings still in use, or are some of them now obsolete?

Answer (score 1):

There is one Unicode (really there are different versions).

You can define any kind of encoding, this do not matter much.

There are UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE as official encoding **form**. Also officially, so in Unicode standard, you have description of UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32.

UCS2 was the old unicode encoding (equal to UTF-16, but with support only to code < 65536), so now it is obsolete (replaced by UTF16, which is capable to code all (also the newer) unicode code points).  UTF-7 is also obsolete.

There are also April fools [UTF-9 and UTF-18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-9_and_UTF-18).

Some application have the UTF8-sig (which is UTF-8 with initial BOM).

On mail, probably you will use UTF8 + BASE64, or some other double encoding.

Mysql uses UTF8MB3 and UTF8MB4, so it specifies UFT-8 but also how many bytes to reserve (3 or 4) per SQL CHAR.

Python3 uses (internally, you probably never see it) a mixed encoding: UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 according to the larger code in the entire string (and the "encoding" is saved together with string length, outside the "true string"). So this is also a sort of encoding.

We have 21 bits to describe any unicode code point. Then we are free to choose any encodings (in a manner that we can get back to the original code point). UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are just the most common (and described in Unicode standard).

Comment: According to [PEP-0393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) Python 3.3+ uses Latin1, UCS-2, or UCS-4 internally based on most efficient storage of the string.  Before that UTF-16LE was used internally for "narrow" builds, and UTF-32LE for "wide" builds.  That PEP eliminated the build difference.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: UCS-2 and UCS-4 are the same as UTF-16 and UTF-32 (for the relative code point range), but you are right, I should use the UCS notation (which is "official"). For latin1 I should still check/think: In that pep there are ascii string (<128) and latin1. Latin1 fits in the answer reasoning (and ascii is just an other kind of object, not more just a "sub-encoding"). I need to read again carefully the PEP and think on how to modify the Python part of the answer. Thank you in any case.

Comment: Instead of 17, I'm sure you mean 21 bits.

Comment: @TomBlodget: yeah. 17 planes, so 21 bits. Thank you for noting it.